# Xbox Arcade games. Can I play them on a PC?

Tags: xbox-360

I've been waiting years (almost) for Shadow Complex to be ported to the PC or the iPad.  Can I somehow play Xbox arcade games on my PC?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, no.  Xbox Live Arcade games cannot be played on a PC.  You'll have to wait for a release on another platform in order to play on that platform.

The Xbox 360's architecture is significantly different from the PC's, although Microsoft offers certain [cross-platform SDK's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) to ease portability between the two.

Comment: Unless he wants to hook his 360 up to a PC monitor and pretend like its on PC

Answer (score 3):

Times have changed and Shadow Complex is now [available for PC](https://www.epicgames.com/shadowcomplex/).

Although in other cases I suppose it's up to the developers to port them. So not impossible, but if you're patient enough...